# Regarding pulse audio

Tags: 20.04, pulseaudio

An ubuntu newbie here. Sorry if this query seems so trivial. It is that I came across the two commands

> pulseaudio -k

> pulseaudio --start

for restarting pulseaudio. Can anybody explain what pulseaudio --k means ? I have googled but can't seem to find an explanation.

Comment: -k | --kill
              Kill an already running PulseAudio daemon of the calling user (Equivalent to sending a SIGTERM).

Comment: If you have manual pages installed in your instance you can run `man pulseaudio` or `man` on almost any command to get this sort of information.